# rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Uploader::Base::Fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After push my app to Heroku, I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, then the error happen:

> rake aborted!
>   NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Uploader::Base::Fog

I've searched my docs, there is no 'CarrierWave::Uploader::Base::Fog'

Comment: show ur gemfile

Comment: push your `Gemfile.lock` on heroku and try to bundle and perform migration

Answer (score 1):

I know why now. Thank you all~

Because my team member has deleted `gem "fog"`, and use `carrierwave-aws` instead, but still keep `config.fog_credentials` in carrierwave.rb. When I change `config.fog_credentials` to `config.aws_credentials`, then I could `heroku run rake db:migrate` normally.

My Gemfile:

```
gem "carrierwave"
gem "mini_magick"
gem "gravatarify"
gem "seo_helper"
gem "font-awesome-sass"
gem "carrierwave-aws"
gem "figaro"
gem "aasm"
gem "redcarpet"
gem "acts_as_list"
```

my previous carrierwave.rb(error):

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.storage :aws
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider: "AWS", # required
      aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], # required
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
      region: ENV["AWS_BUCKET_REGION"] # required
    }
    config.aws_bucket = ENV["AWS_BUCKET_NAME"] # required
  else
    config.storage :file
  end
end
```

my current carrierwave.rb(normal):

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.storage :aws
    config.aws_credentials = {
      provider: "AWS", # required
      aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], # required
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
      region: ENV["AWS_BUCKET_REGION"] # required
    }
    config.aws_bucket = ENV["AWS_BUCKET_NAME"] # required
  else
    config.storage :file
  end
end
```